# Accessing custom template property in helper

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to know why I need to use `Template.instance()` rather than `this` in helpers to access a property attached to a template.

Here is a code where my question arose.

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  this.myProperty = new ReactiveVar(1);
});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  myProperty: function () {
    return Template.instance().myProperty.get(); // this works
    return this.myProperty.get(); // this does not work. (this.myProperty is undefined)
  }
});
```

I thought `this` inside a helper was a reference to the template instance. Why does not the second one work?

Comment: Maybe because it's a singleton. The instance checks for its existence. Take a look at "lazy loading."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the body of a callback under Template.onCreated, Template.onRendered and Template.onDestroyed, `this` is a template instance object.

However, within the helpers, `this` is the data context of the DOM node where the helper was used but not a template instance. for example,

**HTML**

```
{{> myTemplate name='Max'}}

template(name='myTemplate')
  ul
    {{#each users}}
      li {{getAvatar}}
    {{/each}}
```

**JS**

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  console.log(this); // Template.instance()
})

Template.myTemplate.helpers {
  users: function() {
    console.log(this); // {name: 'Max'}
  },
  getAvatar: function() {
    console.log(this); // {_id: ..., username: ..., profile: ..., ...}
  }
}
```

The above is what I know so far, if there are some mistakes, please point it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because inside template helpers `this` is referencing the `Template.currentData()`, not `Template` itself.